# Error de: Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function por Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

En el navegador, reviso en inspeccionar elemento, y me sale el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Me imagino que es por una funcion que uso de Jquery, la cual es la siguiente:

```
var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';
$("#subpagina").html("cargando").load(baseUrl + "Home/Inicio", function () {                
})
```

Me gustaría saber que debería hacer, o como actualizar la funcion de jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

**Actualiza** todas las partes de tu código que tengan la función `load`

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

A lo siguiente:

```
$(window).on('load', function() { ... });
```

Tomado de una publicación original de StackOverflow [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738732/jquery-3-0-url-indexof-error).

Comment: En mi caso, como tengo esta funcion:

var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';
$("#subpagina").html("cargando").load(baseUrl + "Home/Inicio", function () {                
})

Deberia reemplazar por esto????


 seria $("#subpagina").html("cargando").on('load', baseUrl + "Home/Inicio", function() { });

pero no funciona la referencia al enlace

Estoy trabando con MVC

Answer (score 1):

A partir de jQuery 3.0 los métodos `.load()`, `.unload()` y `.error()` fueron removidos por algunos conflictos que ocasionaban, y si desean usarse se debe hacer por medio de `.on()`:

```
.on('load', fn)

.on('error', fn)

.on('unload', fn)
```

[Aquí la nota oficial en inglés.](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

---

En caso que no se pueda/quiera reescribir el código, es posible utilizar también el plugin [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate).

Comment: Pero como lo hago para pasarle la URL?,
ya que lo intento asi, y no funciona:

Comment: ¿qué no funciona? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Pero como lo hago para pasarle la URL?,
ya que lo intento asi, y no funciona:
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
 var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';
 $("#subpagina").html(ajax_load).on('load',baseUrl + href, function() { });

Comment: así está bien, no veo porque no funcionaría, prueba pasando una url directamente.

Comment: me dice lo siguiente:

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /Home/Inicio

Estoy trabajando con MVC, por eso es /Home/Inicio

Comment: ??? alguna idea?